# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir códigos de barra en una ticketera epson TM-U220 desde C#?

Tags: c#

¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede imprimir códigos de barra usando la clase  [RawPrinterHelper](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091)  de Microsoft  en C#? He logrado introducir sencuencias de escape para espaciado y corte de papel (y funcionan bien) pero no encuentro la manera de hacer que se impriman códigos de barra. Aquí adjunto algo del código que tengo.

```
    public void CortarTicket()
    {
        string corte = "\x1B" + "m";                  // caracteres de corte
        string avance = "\x1B" + "d" + "\x09";        // avanza 9 renglones
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, "TEXTO DE PRUEBA"); // texto cualquiera
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, avance); // avanza
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, corte); // corta
    }
```

Comment: Te paso la documentación de ESC/POS. Creo que es el lenguaje que entiende la impresora, ahí detallan cuales son los códigos que tienes que enviar para imprimir un código de barras: http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: si @Giancarlo a sido posible resolver tu inquietud?

Comment: faltaría el código que genera los códigos de barra

Comment: [mria esto ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-print-a-windows-form) , lo vi por ahi a ver si te srive

Answer (score 3):

Esto me funciono a mi.
este es un fragmento de mi código, puedes usarlo como ejemplo...

```
string codigo = "777";

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("codPersona", typeof(string));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewCodigo.Rows)
{
    using (var bc = new BarcodeLib.Barcode())
    {
        var Cod = codigo ;
        table.Rows.Add(Cod, ImageToByteArray(bc.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, codigo)));
    }

}
var reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource("DSCodigo", table);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

***BarcodeLib:***   libreria de c#

***CODE128:***  [Fuente de texto](https://www.dafont.com/es/code-128.font)

en mi caso lo mando a un report viewer para imprimir

**EN TU CASO**

```
public void CortarTicket()
{
    string corte = "\x1B" + "m";                  // caracteres de corte
    string avance = "\x1B" + "d" + "\x09";        // avanza 9 renglones
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, codigo); // texto cualquiera
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, avance); // avanza
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, corte); // corta
}
```

*PRUEBAS Y ME DICES*

Answer (score 1):

Prueba la información de este artículo, [AQUÍ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e9e1556c-4152-4b86-9c0c-bb40fc888318/como-crear-e-imprimir-un-ticket-recibo?forum=repdeves) , propone un código similar al tuyo pero más completo y con impresión en C#.

Comment: Por favor añade a tu respuesta el fragmento de código relevante o un ejemplo. Si el link enlazado cambia, tu respuesta se hace inútil.